# Selecting an element based on immediate follower

Tags: css

Is there any natively supported way of selecting an element based on what it is followed by?

I want to style all h2-tags that are immediately followed by a p-tag. Example:

```
<body>
    <h2>Heading 1</h2>

    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <div>Text</div>

    <h2>Heading 3</h2> <!-- Only this one -->
    <p>Text</p>

    <h2>Heading 4</h2>
    <div>Text</div>

    <h2>Heading 5</h2>
    <div>Text</div>
</body>
```

Comment: No .. only select  based on a preceding element.. adjacent-sibling and generic-sibling selectors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Currently* this is not possible in CSS, as there are no selectors that will select the previous element.

If you were to use jQuery, something like this would work. [**(example here)**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/6zb73/)

```
$('p').prev('h2').css('color','red');
```

When [**CSS4 selectors**](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/) are supported, I believe you will be able to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use a class if I were you and I didn't want to use jQuery.

CSS

```
.h2-with-p{}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <h2>Heading 1</h2>

    <h2>Heading 2</h2>
    <div>Text</div>

    <h2 class="h2-with-p">Heading 3</h2> <!-- Only this one -->
    <p>Text</p>

    <h2>Heading 4</h2>
    <div>Text</div>

    <h2>Heading 5</h2>
    <div>Text</div>
</body>
```